# Como gerar um XML modelo apartir de um SCHEMA XSD usando JAXB?

Tags: java, xml-schema, jaxb

Tenho um Schema .XSD e gostaria de gerar um XML a partir desse modelo. Abaixo eu tenho esse código, no entanto estou utilizando a biblioteca JLibs. Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer algo parecido com a biblioteca JAXB. O arquivo XSD está sendo passado como parâmetro para o método `makeXmlModel()`.

```
public static boolean makeXmlModel(File file)
{
    final XSModel xsModel = new XSParser().parse(file.getPath());
    final XSInstance xsInstance = new XSInstance();
    xsInstance.generateOptionalElements = Boolean.TRUE; // null means random
    final QName rootElement = new QName("http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", "NFe");
    XMLDocument sampleXml;
    try {
         sampleXml = new XMLDocument(new StreamResult("model_xml.xml"), true, 4, null);
         xsInstance.generate(xsModel, rootElement, sampleXml);
         return true;
     } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return false;
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Seu objetivo é gerar  um XML template a partir do XSD? Se for isso, use o utilitário XJC para criar o conjunto de classes JAXB a partir do .XSD, e então, escreva o código criando esses objetos, ao final, use a bliblioteca JAXB para fazer o marshall dos objetos, com os valores mocados.